# New installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with 100 GB partition only uses 50 GB

Tags: partitioning

i run Ubuntu VMs in VMware.

I installed with a partition of 100 GB default LVM.

Only 50 GB are used. 50 GB are unused.

1. I want to grow the / filesystem to use all available space.
2. I want to have the option to incease the partition in VMware and grow the filesystem.
   I did this without LVM by booting frmo gparted CD and increase partition and grow filsystem.

Which are the newest, most comfortable tools?

Definetely no dual boot needed.

GPT to grow behind 2 TB is a must,

kind regards,

Bodo

Comment: Is the size of your / filesystem 50 GB while the entire partition is 100 GB? It's strange, because Ubuntu installer usually uses all available space on a partition you told it to install on. You must have done this purposely during installation, how did you do this? Could you post the output of `df -h` ?

Comment: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   49G   11G   36G  24% /

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors

Comment: `/dev/sda` refers to the entire device, not to a partition. Does the `df` command show any other partitions besides / ?

Comment: Please also edit your question and include the output of `lsblk` command. It should show all disk devices and how the partitions are assigned on them.

Comment: My decision now is not to use LVM

Answer (score 1):

1. Regardless if you use LVM or not, you still have to increase the partition size using for example GParted.
2. After that, if you are using LVM, you should use [lvextend](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvextend) to extend your logical volume to fill up the increased partition. Using `-r` parameter to `lvextend`, you can resize the filesystem together with the logical volume.
3. Or, you can resize the filesystem later, using [resize2fs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs). That's also what you should do if you don't use LVM.

Answer (score 0):

Some things i know that might help:

1. When installing ubuntu, you only need ntfs partition, a swap partition and a /root parition (10-20GB, where your systems files are stored) and /home partition (the rest of your free space, where you can use it like the downloads folder etc). You should choose these when installing the ubuntu.
2. If you want to change the partitions/space after the installation, you cannot do it if you use the disk/Ubuntu (ext4 partitions cannot be resized when used). You need to boot from a live cd/USB and click 'try ubuntu' and from there, open up the GParted program (If its not there you can install it):

   sudo apt update

   sudo apt install gparted

And from Gparted you can change the partition sizing.

Here you can see my Gparted screenshot. My computer is dual boot btw:
[image]

Instructions of setting ubuntu partitions have already been answered: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: In fact, you need only the boot EFI partition (if you are using EFI, otherwise not) and the root partition. All others are optional. Recent Ubuntu distributions can use a swap file instead of a swap partition, and `/home` does not need to be on a separate partition.